# Unexpected reply signature: got "oa{sv}", expected "(oa{sv})"

Tags: qt, dbus, bluez, obex, qtdbus

Using C++/QtDBus.
I'm trying to get a reply from DBus call to function described as:

```
object, dict PullAll(string targetfile, dict filters).
```

I registered (qDBusRegisterMetaType) a type defined as: `typedef QPair< QDBusObjectPath, QVariantMap > Transfer;` 
In `QDBusPendingCallWatcher` handler I'm doing:

```
QDBusPendingReply<Transfer> reply = *pwatcher;
```

I get an error:

> Unexpected reply signature: got `"oa{sv}"`, expected `"(oa{sv})"`

What's wrong? What is parentheses in "(oa{sv})"?

Comment: Maybe the `oa{sv}` is wrapped in an array?

Answer (score 1):

I think the whole message needs to be wrapped in a struct.  At least you have the proper signature otherwise and are getting a response.

```
arrays: []
dict entries: {}
structs: ()
```

I'm not that familiar with QtDbus, but looking at the page for the QDbusArgument Class, you *might* have to do something like this:

```
argument.beginStructure();
argument << mystruct.objectpath << mystruct.array;
argument.endStructure();
```